# Why wont my styles load after downloading locally?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've recently just downloaded a wordpress site I've made and was planning on working on it locally. 
My steps were:

1. Take all FTP files and put it in xampp/htdocs/dev/*myproject*
2. Take a clone of the database, replacing " https://www.myprojecturl.com , http://www.myprojecturl.com etc.
3. Uploaded the database clone to my localhost/phpmyadmin
4. Changed the wp_config to fit the database, and changed the *Rewriterule* & *RewriteBase* to fit my local development url.

It all works, I see content, I can navigate through links. **However**.
No stylesheets are being loaded? 
Chrome console gives me **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"**
And this is due to it trying to load this url for stylesheets: localhost/wp-content (**SKIPPING** the dev/myproject/ url)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Did you updated your URL's in the database to include /dev/myproject ?

Comment: Yeah. I replaced https://www.myprojecturl.com with http://localhost/dev/myproject

Comment: Simple way to fix would be to manually add the  dev/myproject/ to your enqueue function.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna do that for the styles :) but there is a total of 58 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) errors. All because of the same problem (that it doesnt add my dev folder into the url) :/

Comment: Did you change the first 1 or 2 rows of the options table? Did you search the project to see if the last developer incorrectly hardcoded the URL in 58 different places?

Comment: Assets (css/js/img) in your theme loaded over http should start with get_tempate_directory_uri() (or, for child themes, I think, get_stylesheet_url()). If instead the developer used some variables from $_SERVER then it won't work well when you launch in a sub directory.